# Symfony2 plugin for links CSRF protection

Tags: symfony, csrf

Is there any plugin that works this way? I've found KnpRadBundle, but i got working project and adjusting it to a new framework would be very long and unnessesary. Do anybody knows such a plugin?

In KnpRadBundle it's exactly this function: https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpRadBundle/wiki/csrf-protected-links

PS. I'm using Symfony 2.2

Comment: I don't know this bundle but: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection

Comment: Well this is for forms. But i need this for links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and found [this pull request](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/3080) which solves it.

Using the `csrf_token('your_intention')` function you can generate a CSRF token in your Twig template. Later you can check the token using the `form.csrf_provider` service as described in the pull request.